# Apollo Client Throws network exception with Kotlin and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apollo-client

I have the following POC i'm working on with Spring boot, Kotlin and ApolloClient

Controller:

```
@RestController
class ControllerExample(private val serviceExample: ServiceExample) {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())

    @RequestMapping(value = ["/apollo"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
    @Throws(ApolloException::class)
    fun getApolloData(): ApolloResponse<MemberQuery.Data> {

            try {
                coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val response = serviceExample.getMemberData()
                    logger.info("response $response")
                    return response
                }
            }catch (ex : Exception){
                logger.error("Error: " + ex.localizedMessage)
            }

    }
}
```

Service layer:

```
@Service
class ServiceExample {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

    suspend fun getMemberData(): ApolloResponse<MemberQuery.Data>{

        val apolloClient = ApolloClient.Builder()
                .serverUrl("https://mock-url")
                .addHttpHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build()

        try {
            val response=  apolloClient.query(MemberQuery()).execute()
            logger.info("response >>>>> ${response}")
            return response
        } catch (ex : ApolloException){
            logger.error("error >>>>> ${ex.localizedMessage}")
            throw ex
        }
    }
}
```

However, When I send the request I get an error as:

```
Failed to execute GraphQL http network
```

I'm not sure If I'm missing something but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the controller you're assigning `response` to a variable, and logging it, but don't you also need to return it? I'm not sure if that's the cause of your issue, but it certainly looks like a problem.

Comment: I'm putting breaking points on the controller, I don't care if the controller return anything as the issue occurs on the service layer where the exception is thrown